# How to determine which (object) control has been clicked?

Tags: fabricjs

I'm after some advice re "how to determine which (object) control has been clicked"?

On mouse:over I hide the corner controls (and the border):

Image -> https://github.com/Robinyo/my-2d-diagram-editor/blob/master/client/content/images/my-2d-diagram-editor-with-ports.png

On mouse:down I use getCenterPoint() (of the mouse:over target) to start drawing a line:

Image -> https://github.com/Robinyo/my-2d-diagram-editor/blob/master/client/content/images/my-2d-diagram-editor-with-connections.png

On mouse:move I update the (connector) lines x2 and y2, and on mouse:up I use getCenterPoint() (of the mouse:over target) as the line's end point.

What I would like to do is use the nearest connect point (ml, mt, mr, mb) rather than getCenterPoint().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

update to latest fabric js if your application allows it, because this fix is recent.

then on mouse up you can check for:

```
object.__corner
```

That should have value 'mt', 'mr'... and so on.
Be carefull that if i'm not wrong fabricjs check first for object, and then if it fails it check for corner click.

```
(target.containsPoint(xy) || target._findTargetCorner(pointer))
```

It means that it will first check for the bounding box and then for the corners. In other words the corner targeting will work just in the outer part of the corner.

Comment: Got it -> https://github.com/Robinyo/my-2d-diagram-editor/blob/master/client/content/images/my-2d-diagram-editor-with-connections-2.png

Thanks :)